# One file don't have syntax colors

Tags: phpstorm

I have problem with PhpStorm on my PC. Only one file `HomeController.php` doesn't have syntax highlighting, but has it when I open this file on my laptop.

Do you know why is it that?

Comment: Without seeing the offending file we can't offer any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure you have the `<?php` tag at the top of the file? Also double check if the file extension is correct.

Comment: And you can right click on the file in the left hand explorer to ensure that it's being treated as a source file. You might have accidentally toggled that via a key combo or something.

Comment: I have a whole bitbucket project, so I have the same file on both computers. In addition, I removed ".idea" and other files from the project and it did not help. I also thought at first that something was wrong with the file, that it is missing <?php etc. However, this is not because on the second computer in Phpstorm this file is displayed normally

Answer (score 2):

Please check if `HomeController.php` is added to text file patterns in **Preferences | Editor | File types -> Text file type**. Removing this pattern should solve your problem.

If it's not the case, see if the file is marked as plain text (the option is in the file right-click menu). In this case, the option to mark it back as a PHP file is also in the context menu.